# Replacing html in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a first div tag on a webpage. It contains some angular scope variables. I want to replace it with a second div tag which also contains some other angular scope variables when something happens.

The first way I tried is to use "ng-show". I add both the first and the second div on html and set the first div tag to be visible and second one to be invisible by using ng-show and ng-hide.

```
<div ng-show="showFirstDiv">

</div>

<div ng-hide="showFirstDiv">

</div>
```

When I change `$scope.showFirstDiv` from `true` to `false` within the relevant controller and call `$scope.$apply()`, the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` attribute values change (after using inspecting element in a browser).

However, the visibility of those two html tags did not change. The first div didn't disappear even with `ng-show="false"` and second div did not show up even with `ng-hide="false"`.

What should I do? Is there a better way to replace a div with another div in angular while both divs contain angular scope variables?

Comment: you are doing it wrong. why don't you use http://plnkr.co/ to show us your issue ?

Comment: i think your approach is correct, make sure you are setting boolean false/true and not "false" or "true". plnkr is next step.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, you shouldn't need `$scope.$apply()` if it's working correctly. Would you mind showing more of your code? (eg Where the controller is defined in the HTML, the controller JS itself)

Comment: I would say Angular isn't being booted if you're not getting any result with `ng-show="false"`... try `console.log('test')` in one of your controllers to see if the controller is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ngIf`?

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.

```
<div ng-if="showFirstDiv">

</div>

<div ng-if="!showFirstDiv">

</div>
```

Comment: `ng-show` works just as well, but he does need to use the `!showFirstDiv` negation in the second `div` for the two to "swap" out.